# SwiftUI NSSearchField text becomes stuck

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

Since SwiftUI does not natively support a search component in macOS 11 I am wrapping `NSSearchField`. This mostly works until the text grows outside of the current field's width where you would usually see the text scroll as you're typing. This does not happen using my wrapper nor does it work using many similar snippets I've found online. The view also does not allow moving the cursor past the end of the visible portion of text.

The first item is my `SearchBar` whereas the second is a `TextField`. Notice how the text continues off the trailing side (as expected).

[image: NSSearchField wrapper and TextField]

```
import SwiftUI

struct SearchBar: NSViewRepresentable {
    private var placeholder: String
    @Binding var text: String
    
    init(_ placeholder: String, text: Binding<String>) {
        self.placeholder = placeholder
        _text = text
    }
    

    class Coordinator: NSObject, NSSearchFieldDelegate {

        @Binding var text: String

        init(text: Binding<String>) {
            _text = text
        }
        
        func controlTextDidChange(_ obj: Notification) {
            if let searchField = obj.object as? NSSearchField {
                text = searchField.stringValue
            }
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> SearchBar.Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(text: $text)
    }

    func makeNSView(context: NSViewRepresentableContext<SearchBar>) -> NSSearchField {
        let searchField = NSSearchField(frame: .zero)
        searchField.delegate = context.coordinator
        searchField.placeholderString = placeholder
        return searchField
    }

    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSSearchField, context: NSViewRepresentableContext<SearchBar>) {
        nsView.stringValue = text
    }
}

struct SearchBar_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    @State private static var text = ""

    static var previews: some View {
        SearchBar("Search", text: $text)
    }
}
```

Comment: SwiftUI 3.0 (iOS 15) already has navite `.searchable(text: Binding<String>)`

Comment: @Asperi, yes, but this is related to macOS and macOS 11 specifically (which does not have native support).

Answer (score 0):

You need to subclass the NSSearchField and enable the `isScrollable`.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct Searchbar: NSViewRepresentable {
    private var placeholder: String
    @Binding var text: String
    
    init(_ placeholder: String, text: Binding<String>) {
        self.placeholder = placeholder
        _text = text
    }
    
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, NSSearchFieldDelegate {
        @Binding var text: String
        
        init(text: Binding<String>) {
            _text = text
        }
        
        func controlTextDidChange(_ obj: Notification) {
            guard let searchField = obj.object as? CustomSearchField else { return }
            text = searchField.stringValue
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Searchbar.Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(text: $text)
    }
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> CustomSearchField {
        let searchField = CustomSearchField(frame: .zero)
        
        // delegate
        searchField.delegate = context.coordinator
        // placeholder
        searchField.placeholderString = placeholder
        // layout
        searchField.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
        
        return searchField
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: CustomSearchField, context: Context) {
        nsView.stringValue = text
    }
    
    class CustomSearchField: NSSearchField {
        override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
            super.init(frame: frameRect)
            
            self.cell = CustomSearchFieldCell(textCell: "")
        }
        
        required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
    }
    
    class CustomSearchFieldCell: NSSearchFieldCell {
        override init(textCell string: String) {
            super.init(textCell: string)
            
            self.isEditable = true
            self.isBordered = true
            self.drawsBackground = true
            self.isBezeled = true
            self.isSelectable = true
            self.isScrollable = true // <--- here!!
        }
        
        required init(coder: NSCoder) {
            fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        }
    }
}

struct SearchBar_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    @State private static var text = ""
    
    static var previews: some View {
        Searchbar("Search", text: $text)
                .preferredColorScheme(.light)
                .frame(width: 150)
    }
}
```